# On the finite non-nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, nilpotent-groups

Let $G=P \ltimes Q$ be a finite non-nilpotent group, 
where $P \in {\rm Syl}_q(G)$ is non-cyclic $p$-subgroup and $Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(G)$ is non-abelian. Suppose that $\bar{Q}:=Q/ \Phi(Q) \cong \Bbb{Z}_q \times \Bbb{Z}_q$ and $\bar{Q}$ is an irreducible $P$-module and $\Phi(Q)$ is minimal normal subgroup of $G$. I want to know why $Q^{\prime}/\Gamma_3(Q)$ is cyclic? Also i want conclude that $|\Phi(Q)|=q$.

MY work: I know since $Q$ is nilpotent $\exists n \in \Bbb{N} \ ;\ \Gamma_n(Q)=1$. Also we have $\Gamma_1(Q)=Q$ and $\Gamma_2(Q)=Q^{\prime}$ and 
$Q^{\prime}/\Gamma_3(Q) \leq Z(Q/\Gamma_3(Q))$.

Also i know $Q^{\prime} \leq \Phi(Q)$(Because $Q$ is nilpotent), and since $Q^{\prime} \trianglelefteq G$, we get $Q^{\prime}=\Phi(Q)$.

Comment: Since $\Phi(Q)$ is minimal normal in $G$, we must have $\Phi(Q) \le Z(Q)$, so $\Gamma_3(Q)=1$.

Comment: How we conclude that $|\Phi(Q)|=q$?

Comment: @Derek Hol When $\Gamma_3(Q)=1$ we have $Q^{\prime} \leq Z(Q)$. Why $Q^{\prime}$ is cyclic?

Comment: The commutator map is bilinear in nilpotent groupsof class $2$ so, since  $Q = \langle x,y \rangle$, is a $2$-generator group, $Q' = \langle [x,y] \rangle$ is cyclic.

Comment: @Derek Hol I dont know this concept "The commutator map is bilinear in nilpotent groupsof class 2". can i ask you tell me a reference to understand this concept?

Comment: If $G$ is nilpotent of class $2$, then  $[xy,z] = [x,z][y,z]$ and $[x,yz]=[x,y][x,z]$ for all $x,y,z \in G$.

Comment: Yes that right, thanks.